# scrapy doesn't add fields which are not present in all items?

Tags: python, scrapy, field

I get fields a,b,c from a link and yield an OrderedDict. 
But if a condition is met I don't yield yet, first I do a request for another link , transmit the a,b,c dictionary to that request (through partial) and also get fields d,e from the second link and yield d,e,a,b,c.

So some items should have the fields d,e,a,b,c
and some items should have just a,b,c

When I print the OrderedDicts they are correct:

```
the second OrderedDict has keys d,e,a,b,c
the first OrderedDict has keys a,b,c
```

But in the exported .csv file I only see a,b,c columns.

So my question is : is scrapy not showing fields which are not present in all items ?

Note: by field I just mean column header, I do NOT use scrapy's Item and Fields classes, I just use OrderedDict

Update: I've managed to solve my problem by yielding a single dict (updating the first dict). But I am still curious about the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first have a quick look at related source code in [`scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/exporters.py#L203):

```
    def export_item(self, item):
        if self._headers_not_written:
            self._headers_not_written = False
            self._write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export(item)

        fields = self._get_serialized_fields(item, default_value='',
                                             include_empty=True)
        values = list(self._build_row(x for _, x in fields))
        self.csv_writer.writerow(values)

    def _write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export(self, item):
        if self.include_headers_line:
            if not self.fields_to_export:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    # for dicts try using fields of the first item
                    self.fields_to_export = list(item.keys())
                else:
                    # use fields declared in Item
                    self.fields_to_export = list(item.fields.keys())
            row = list(self._build_row(self.fields_to_export))
            self.csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

The exporter itself deals with streaming data, which means it cannot buffer *all* spider outputs before writing to the files. Thus the CSV exporter has to infer the headers from only the 1st item.

If you're using `scrapy.Item`, there shall have been no problem at all. Otherwise if you're using Python's `dict`, fieldnames of the 1st item would be used as the CSV headers.