# Scrapy: Field Name Derived from Page Content

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-item

I am looking at pages that are structured in the following way, though the exact elements may not be a `table`. In general, there are `key-value pairs` where the count of `keys` are limited up to 3 per page (but not necessarily in a particular order) and the `keys` vary from page to page (and I otherwise have no way to know what all of the `keys` may be without pre-scraping every possible page). Also, there should not be repeats of a key in the same page (e.g., A -> 1, B -> 2, A -> 3). I don't have issues isolating the keys, values from the page using XPath, just on storing and exporting the values from my Spider.

[image]

**Approach 1**

If I use the `dictionary` approach with something like this pseudocode:

```
    for th, td in table:
        item[th.text()] = td.text()
```

Then the result would only show values for A, B, C because those values exist in the first page processed and only the [headers and values for the first request are maintained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806007/scrapy-doesnt-add-fields-which-are-not-present-in-all-items).

**Approach 2**

If I use the `scrapy.item.Item()` and `scrapy.item.Field()` approach with something like this:

```
    class MyItem(Item):
        A = Field()
        B = Field()
        C = Field()
```

Then I have no way of declaring a value for the unknown values (shown as ...). And I'll receive a KeyError when trying to set the value (either directly or using an ItemLoader.add_value()).

I am using `Python 3.8` and `Scrapy 2.4.1`.

Comment: How about exporting to a different format? Approach 1 will work exporting to JSON.

Comment: @tomjn Thanks! While not perfect, this is a reasonable solution (at least I don't lose data).